# How to automate a chat box questions and answers using Selenium/Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

our application is like chat bot where user can ask business related questions and that chat bot will reply according to your questions.so howto automate it in selenium

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the question and in response you will receive certain response. You could discuss with developers and look for the certain set of words in response which the developers have implemented using NLP and based on the number of hits of matching words you can predict if the answers are correct. Or you can match the entire answers if they are pre-decided.